# How to stop Authentication for Provider Hosted APP when its host to different domain IIS

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, iis7

I have hosted my **Provider Hosted APP website** to **"Dedicated server domain IIS"** and installed APP to SharePoint Site which is in **different domain**.

Now when I open the APP, its promoting for the authentication and I have to pass IIS(dedicated server) domain credentials. I don't want to give my hosted server credentials, then how to stop prompting for authentication?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you turned off Windows Authentication on the IIS website? Are you accesing the provider hosted app directly or through SharePoint (the second one is the correct method)?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I am accessing APP through SharePoint and as per Microsoft Article we can host our SharePoint APP to another server but its asking Windows Authentication. How can we stop that authentication while accessing APP from SharePoint?